# android- php - mysql: json + rmi

Tags: php, android, json, rmi

hello  i'm developping an android application that communicates with a phpscript using json to  manipulate a mysql database. there is a class that do the processing called "user functions" :
that login logout, create user, delete user, etc ...
can i export this function to the server too using rmi so i can make my app more light ? so i will have this architecture:
[image]

is it a good idea or a bad one ?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is that if I wanted to use RMI, I would just have a java app on the server side to interact with the DB, rather than introducing another serialization process (to JSON) and implement a second PHP API on the server.